# PHP include doesn't work for TwitterOAuth.php, but when I copy and paste its contents directly everything is fine

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, include, twitter-oauth

I am running into problems trying to include TwitterOAuth.php from https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth to use the Twitter API.

My problem is this: I have a file called twitter.php in the same directory as my TwitterOAuth.php and OAuth.php files. When I try to use this snippet of code to connect:

```
include("TwitterOAuth.php");

//I actually fill in these values in my code, no worries...
$apikey = //"...";
$apisecret = //"...";
$accesstoken = //"...";
$accesssecret = //"...";

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($apikey, $apisecret, $accesstoken, $accesssecret);
print_r($connection);
```

I get this error (line 239 is the $connection=new TwitterOAuth(...) line):

Fatal error: Class 'TwitterOAuth' not found in /home/sites/(mydomain)/public_html/twitteroauth-master/src/twitter.php on line 239

However, if I copy and paste the entire contents of the TwitterOAuth.php file, replacing the line at which I call include("TwitterOAuth.php"); with those contents, everything works fine. I've also tried using include_once, require, and require_once, to no avail.

Please advise - I am very new to PHP and have no idea why *copying and pasting works when include() doesn't.*

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on ... more likely then not the include isn't going through and you just aren't seeing the error. you can do `include(__DIR__."/TwitterOAuth.php");` and probably get some love. In php relative directories are resolved by the current working directory (and include path) which is not necessarily the file in which the include is defined.

Comment: Looks to me like you've got it setup ok and that the oauth extension is available and ready to use on the server. This is probably some silly mistake you made somewhere. Check that the files are indeed uploaded to the correct directory. Try using single quotes in your include or require_once functions when calling the file. Make sure you place the include on top of everything else. Verify that TwitterOAuth.php is readable. Lastly, check the php/apache logs.

Comment: @EmirMemic I know this thread is 2 years old but after hours of trying to figure out WHY I couldn't get the includes to work like the original question. That was until I read your comment. I thought to myself, nah...no way, the files have to be there because I am using Git. Lo and behold, there was no "src" folder because I use the same folder name to hold files and the "src/" name was added to gitignore.

Answer (score 3):

You should modify:

```
include("TwitterOAuth.php");
```

into:

```
include 'TwitterOAuth.php';
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
```

to be able to access the `TwitterOAuth` in its defined namespace.

It is recommended to use `include '<file>'` because `include` is a special language construct, not a function, and should not be confused with a function.

Answer (score 1):

Are your files in the same directory? Since you are using include("TwitterOAuth.php"); then that means the files exist under the same directory. If it were include("../TwitterOAuth.php"); Then the file would exist in the parent directory

Comment: Thank you for the input, but as I mentioned above, all of my files exist in the same directory.