# Class not found PHP

Tags: php, class, twitter, directory, twitter-oauth

I used [**THIS twitter librabry**](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) and getting this error. Can anyone tell where i am going wrong ?

**ERROR**

```
Fatal error: Class 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Config' not found in D:\wamp\www\Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth.php on line 17
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

require_once("Abraham/TwitterOAuth/TwitterOAuth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library you downloaded in step 3

//keys and tokens initialised


function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

echo json_encode($tweets);
echo $tweets; //testing remove for production   
?>
```

Comment: You can take look at this question and its answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745553/php-include-doesnt-work-for-twitteroauth-php-but-when-i-copy-and-paste-its-con?rq=1

Comment: @Esteban now error is showing `
{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that this is correct way? :

`require_once("Abraham/TwitterOAuth/TwitterOAuth.php");`

you could try:

```
require_once("Abraham/autoload.php"); 
require_once("Abraham/TwitterOAuth/TwitterOAuth.php"); 
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
```

Comment: now `Fatal error: Class 'TwitterOAuth' not found in D:\wamp\www\test.php on line 36`

Answer (score 0):

`TwitterOAuth` uses the `Config` class - but it does not get loaded automatically. You could `require` this class - or use a classloader. The best approach would be using `composer` to manage your dependencies (which comes with a class loader).

Comment: there is a composer.json file but how to use it ? @fateddy

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your 
`vendor\abraham\twitteroauth\src` :

Is there a `Config.php` ?

I encountered this problem causes by a `.gitignore` placed upper in the project. This one was containing a line `config.php` ...
I changed it to `\config.php` to remove only the top config file and enable the file in abraham's library